# Loop through Checkboxes in Placholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to find a way to loop through all the controls of type 'Checkbox' in a ASP Placeholder, and then do something with the control in the loop.

Problem is I can't access the controls...here is what I have so far...

```
string selections = "";

foreach (CheckBox ctrl in phProductLines.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>)
{
     selections += ctrl.Text + ", ";            
}
```

But I'm getting the error - "Foreach cannot operate on a method group".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OfType` is  a  method so you have to add `()`:

```
foreach (CheckBox ctrl in phProductLines.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    // ...
}
```

By the way, you can use LINQ and `String.Join` to get your desired result:

```
string result = string.Join(", ", phProductLines.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
            .Select(chk => chk.Text));
```

If you only want the `Checked` checkboxes:

```
string result = string.Join(", ", phProductLines.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
            .Where(chk => chk.Checked)
            .Select(chk => chk.Text));
```